# How to limit the length in Regex?

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I'm having some issue with regex which I'm sure someone here could help me with.
I'm scrapping a web page and want to find the first instance of a Wordpress link. So for instance I have something like this:

```
preg_match("/<link\shref=.+\/wp-content\/themes\/(.+)\//", $site, $match);
```

The problem is, there are pages which have images from Wordpress sites with the same `wp-content/theme` structure, then what happens is the regex catches the first `<link` on the page and goes down the page till the `wp-content/theme/` image, and gives me a false positive.

I've been trying to fix this but I can't seem to succeed. I thought of somehow regexing the head and searching only in there, but I wasn't able to do it.
What I really need to do is find a `<link` then find the next `>` and only if the `wp/content/` exists between them give me a positive result.

I'm not exactly extremely knowledgeable with regex. I know the basics I guess but this one might be a little bit out of my reach.

I would appreciate any input here, I'm sure there is a simple way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You can use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php, then http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php and check the `href` for your term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here, only one of which you are asking about.

The problem you are asking about can be solved by saying "go on until you find a `>` which can be solved by using `[^>]+` instead of `.+`

The other problem is that you are using regex to parse HTML. Use a HTML parsing library instead.